# Expected Value of Random Process when allowed to retry

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let's say there is a random process that has **36 possible outcomes**.

33 of these outcomes give you a value of **50**
and rest three give a value of **60, 75 and 100.**

What is the expected value of this process, when we are allowed to retry it once. And the same outcome cannot appear again on retrying.

So the average value of the process without retrying is 52.36. But I am not able to calculate what would the expected value be if we can retry. 
For example, if we get 50 on the first time, and we choose to retry then the possible outcomes is reduced to 35, with the expected value being

**((50*32) + 60 + 75 + 100 )/35 = 52.42**

And considering that in the first place we can only get 50 33/36 times means the expected value over the entire process should be

**(33*52.42 + 60 + 75 + 100)/36 = 54.57** ?

Comment: When the result in the first run is $50$, shouldn't the possible values in the second run be only $60, 75$ and $100$?

Comment: When we retry does the second-try outcome is taken? Or greater from those 2 tries? Do we have a strategy, e.g. when we got >50 then we won't retry?

Comment: The reason that I believe we should retry only when we get 50 is because that is the only value less than the expected value ~ 52. If we get 60, 75 or 100 we would not want to retry as it is greater than the expected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your equations, I interpret the situation as: (a) if you get $>50$ the first time you won't retry, and (b) if you get $50$ the first time you retry and your overall result is the second-try result (which necessarily $\ge$ your first result of $50$).

First of all, is my interpretation correct?

If so, your method is entirely valid.  However you have some rounding errors.

$$((50 \times 32) + 60 + 75 + 100 )/35 = \color{red}{367 \over 7} = 52.42\color{red}{8571}... \approx 52.4\color{red}{3}$$

$$(33\times \color{red}{367 \over 7} + 60 + 75 + 100)/36 = \color{red}{3439 \over 63} = 54.5\color{red}{87301}...$$

So as you can see, after fixing the rounding issues your answer agrees with the alternate method in the answer by @RossMillikan

Answer (score 1):

Presumably if you get more than $50$ on the first try you keep it.  You have $\frac 1{36}$ chance of getting $60$ on the first try and $\frac {33}{36}\cdot \frac 1{35}$ chance of getting $60$ on the second try because you have to get a $50$ on the first to get $60$ on the second.  The chance of getting $60$ is then $\frac 1{36}+\frac {33}{36}\cdot \frac 1{35}=\frac {68}{1260}$.  The chance of getting $75$ or $100$ is the same.  The chance you are stuck with $50$ is then $1-3\cdot \frac {68}{1260}=\frac {1056}{1260}$  Now we can calculate the expected value as you have the chance of each outcome.  It is $\frac {1056}{1260}\cdot 50+\frac {68}{1260}(60+75+100)=\frac{68780}{1280}\approx 54.5873$

You can also calculate the chance you end with $50$ by noting you have to get $50$ twice, so it is $\frac {33}{36} \cdot \frac {32}{35}=\frac {1056}{1260}$.  Of course it agrees.